# String indices must be integers - substring

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I'm tying to get a length string and have the program count and display the total number of letter `"T"` found in the entered string but getting the following error. Line 13 is this:  `if string[0,counter] == "T":`

Any suggestions?

> File "python", line 13, in 
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
#Variable to hold number of Ts in a string
numTs = 0

#Get a sentence from the user.
string = input("Enter a string: ")

#Count the number of Ts in the string.
for counter in range(0,len(string)):
  if string[0,counter] == "T":
    numTs = numTs + 1

#Display the number of Ts.
print("That string contains {} instances of the letter T.".format(numTs))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Count the number of Ts in the string.
for counter in range(0,len(string)):
  if string[0,counter] == "T":
    numTs = numTs + 1
```

Your index for `string` is a `tuple`: `0, counter`.

Instead you should just use the index `counter`.

```
for counter in range(0,len(string)):
  if string[counter] == "T":
    numTs = numTs + 1
```

If your goal is not merely to learn how to implement algorithms like this, a more idiomatic way is to use the standard library's [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
>>> string = 'STack overflow challenge Topic'
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(string)
>>> 
>>> c['T']
2
```

Comment: Thanks, using the index counter did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input("Enter the string:\n");count = 0
for chars in string:
    if chars == "T" or chars == "t":
        count = count + 1
print ("Number of T's in the string are:",count)
```

This will find the number of t's in the given string